# Javafx how to simulate a right click event on Tab

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a `Tab` and i want to programmatically trigger a right click event, to pop up my `ContextMenu`, set on the Tab

```
Tab tab = new Tab("Some tab that has no graphic and doesnt need graphic");
tab.setContextMenu(new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("go")));
//add it to a tabPane.
//now when i want to trigger a right click i do this
 Event rightClick = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 0, 0, 0, 0, MouseButton.SECONDARY,
                1, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, null);
MouseEvent.fireEvent(tab, rightClick);//but it doesnt work why??
```

i have even altered the code this way

```
 Event rightClick = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 0, 0, 0, 0, MouseButton.SECONDARY,
                1, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, null); //still no
```

on any ordinary node the above code works, just `Tab`

*i need a javafx way*

Comment: impersonate = simulate?

Comment: @shmosel thanks, and yes, i want to trigger the right click when i want to.

Comment: is the purpose just to manually display the ContextMenu?

Comment: yes Peter, yes, but i feel to manaully display the ContextMenu by the ContextMenu.show() method is really a long way when it comes to Tab, but yes that is the reason i want to do that, any help is appreciated @Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `Tab` doesn't support mouse events. The `Tab` class is not a `Node` subclass, i.e. it doesn't represent the actual tab UI you see in the header of the tab pane: it represents the model for the tab. (It encapsulates the text, whether it is selected, etc.) The events is supports are things like `onCloseRequested`, `onClosed`, `onSelectionChanged`. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html).

To fire a mouse event, you need to fire it on the actual UI represented by the tab. You can only get this with a CSS lookup, which is a bit of a hack, but it works.

I would actually recommend calling `show` on the context menu, instead of firing the event, since that more semantically represents what you want to do. As far as I can see, you still need to look up the node, because you need to find its location on the screen, but you could just do `contextMenu.show(tab.getTabPane().getScene().getWindow());` and the context menu would appear *somewhere*. But it's better to get the reference to the node:

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ShowTabContextMenu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab");
        tab.setId("myTab");

        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("Choice 1"), new MenuItem("Choice 2"));
        tab.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 400, 400);
        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));

        pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
            Node theTab = tabPane.lookup("#myTab");
            contextMenu.show(theTab, Side.RIGHT, 0, 0);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        pause.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you really want to simulate an event, you should simulate a `ContextMenuEvent` rather than a mouse event:

```
    pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
        Node theTab = tabPane.lookup("#myTab");
        // contextMenu.show(theTab, Side.RIGHT, 0, 0);
        Bounds tabBounds = theTab.getBoundsInLocal();
        double centerX = tabBounds.getMinX() + tabBounds.getWidth()/2;
        double centerY = tabBounds.getMinY()+tabBounds.getHeight()/2;
        Point2D location = theTab.localToScreen(centerX, centerY);
        double x = location.getX();
        double y = location.getY();
        Event event = new ContextMenuEvent(ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED, centerX, centerY, x, y, false, new PickResult(theTab, x, y));
        Event.fireEvent(theTab, event);
    });
```

but that just seems wrong to me: no actual event has occurred, you just want the context menu to show.